# How to type ^A in unix shell script/VI

Tags: shell, unix, vi

I am new to unix and writing script to extract data in delimited file format.

want to use ^A as delimiter , can you please suggest how to type/insert it

Answer (score 6):

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.

According to your system configuration, you may need to type other key sequence. Check the output of `stty -a`, especially `lnext`:

```
$ stty -a | grep lnext
lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: `<kbd>V</kbd>`... Well, today is a well spent day as I've learned a new thing!

Comment: @gboffi, <kbd>test</kbd>. I also learned that `kbd` does not work in comment ;)

Answer (score 5):

In `vi`, you can generally type <kbd>CTRL-V</kbd> in insert mode, followed by another control character.

That's also true in the `bash` shell if you're in `vi` editing mode (entered with <kbd>CTRL-K</kbd>).

In `emacs` editing mode (usually entered by using the up arrow key), you would use <kbd>CTRL-Q</kbd> as a prefix command, before entering the character you want.

For example, here's my shell session showing the use of <kbd>CTRL-V</kbd><kbd>CTRL-A</kbd> (which shows up as `^A`):

```
pax> echo -n "^A" | od -b
0000000 001
0000001
```

You can see that the octal dump of the single character is indeed <kbd>CTRL-A</kbd>, or `001`.

Comment: if "^A" needs to be addded in grep pattern search (not in VI) ctr+v ctr+A is not working there

Comment: @Nishad, depends on what's handling the input. You say non-vi but don't specify _where_ you're entering the data.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is '\001', but I'm not a very experienced shell scripter.

Here is a link that helped:

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/ch45_35.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can type `:h digraph-table` to see the digraph-table text that describes the character.
Then you can input <kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd> and the digraph line consponsed to your character.