# BigQuery load - NULL is treating as string instead of empty

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

My requirement is to pull the data from Different sources(Facebook,youtube, double click search etc) and load into BigQuery. When I try to pull the data, in some of the sources I was getting "NULL" when the column is empty.

I tried to load the same data to BigQuery and BigQuery is treating as a string instead of NULL(empty).

Right now replacing ""(empty string) where NULL is there before loading into BigQuery.  Instead of doing this is there any way to load the file directly without any manipulations(replacing).

Thanks,

Comment: How are you loading the data? Through the command line or are you using any programming language?

Comment: Hi I am using python API to load into BigQuery.

Comment: Would you mind sharing some code? This is important since there are at least two python package to use for loading data and I just want to make sure I know which one you are using.

Comment: There is a load option that you can use for this case: configuration.load.nullMarker

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load

Comment: is there a way we can load this from web console? My managers are tyring to load same data some times via console.

Answer (score 4):

What is the file format of source file e.g. CSV, New Line Delimited JSON, Avro etc?

The reason is CSV treats an empty string as a null and the *NULL* is a string value. So, if you don't want to manipulate the data before loading you should save the files in NLD Json format.

As you mentioned that you are pulling data from Social Media platforms, I assume you are using their REST API and as a result it will be possible for you to save that data in NLD Json instead of CSV.

Answer to your question *is there a way we can load this from web console?*:
Yes, Go to your bigquery project console https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/ and create table in a dataset where you can specify the source file and table schema details.

From Comment section (for the convenience of other viewers):

**Is there any option in bq commands for this?**

Try this:
`bq load --format=csv --skip_leading_rows=1 --null_marker="NULL" yourProject:yourDataset.yourTable ~/path/to/file/x.csv Col1:string,Col2:string,Col2:integer,Col3:string`

Comment: Thanks Pulkit for your reply. You said its possible in web console but later part i didnt get. I know how to create tables though web console. Is there an option to say that treat NULL as empty instead of string while upload via web console. As mention Hua Zhang we have an option while pulling via API configuration.load.nullMarker like that is there an option.

Comment: I don't think there is a option to change "configuration.load.nullMarker" in Console. It should follow default configurations for each file format.

Comment: thanks Pulkit for your reply. Is there any option in bq commands for this?

Comment: Try something like: `bq load --format=csv --skip_leading_rows=1 --null_marker="NULL"  yourProject:yourDataset.yourTable ~/path/to/file/x.csv Col1:string,Col2:string,Col2:integer,Col3:string`

Comment: if columns are string doesn't have any issues. Suppose if the column is float or integer then it is throwing an error.

Comment: You might have already tried it, but I have to ask. Have you tried loading everything as a string?

Comment: yes if i load everything as string then it is working fine

Comment: My suggestion is you store everything as string in *staging* or *landing* table.That way you don't have to manipulate the source data, therefore, source system stays intact. You can convert columns to desired data types after the data is in Bigquery and work with that table downstream. On the side note, Bigquery team is unlikely to change the approach to treat *NULL* string literal as NULL for CSV file format because that might affect other use-cases. I hope we are having this discussion because you want to standardize the loading pattern and not just reduce the effort to load one file :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Pulkit. I am doing the same thing right now.

Answer (score 3):

You may consider running a command similar to: bq load --field_delimiter="\t" --null_marker="\N" --quote="" \
PROJECT:DATASET.tableName gs://bucket/data.csv.gz table_schema.json

More details can be gathered from the replies to the "Best Practice to migrate data from MySQL to BigQuery" [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41774233/best-practice-to-migrate-data-from-mysql-to-bigquery).